# php add words without repeating random position in the string

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, repeat

I have a string and key words array like this.

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa";

$keywordsArr = array('FOOO' => 3,'BAR' => 2);
```

So I need to put these keywords into the string with number of times according to the key words array as following. And without repeating these key words.

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor FOOO sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing BAR elit. Aenean commodo FOOO ligula eget dolor. Aenean FOOO massa BAR";
// 3 times FOOO and 2 times BAR
```

**Without repeating like this.**

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor FOOO FOOO FOOO sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing BAR BAR elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa";
```

Anyone can help me? Really appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $string = "Lorem ipsum FOO dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis";
$keywordsArr = array('FOO' => 4, 'BAR' => 2);
$sResult = addWordToString($string, $keywordsArr);


function addWordToString($string, $keywordsArr) {

    $dStringLength = strlen($string);
    //converting the string into an array depending on the spaces
    $aStringContent = explode(' ', $string);
    $dLength = count($aStringContent);
    //loop the keyword array
    foreach ($keywordsArr as $key => $value) {
        //check if the word occured the number times of value
        $sRegularExperssion = "/$key/";
        $dNumberOfMatches = preg_match($sRegularExperssion, $string);
        if ($dNumberOfMatches >= $value) {
            echo "you are done, the word $key already exist $dNumberOfMatches times";
        } else if ($dNumberOfMatches >= 0) {
            $dRemainingTimes = $value - $dNumberOfMatches;

            $dStep = (int) ($dLength / $dRemainingTimes);

            for ($dIndex = 0; $dIndex < $dRemainingTimes; $dIndex++) {
                $dPosition = $dStep * $dIndex;
                array_splice($aStringContent, $dPosition, 0, $key);
            }


        }
    }
    $sResult = implode(' ', $aStringContent);

    return $sResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Glad to say and this is worked well.It is adding keywords number of times as the keyword array. No repeated. But specific positions only. Can I add it to random position?Thanks

Comment: yes , replace the variable $dPosition with the following :  $dPosition = rand(0 ,$dLength);

Comment: Worked perfect. sometimes there are repeat same keywords.Thanks!

Comment: to cope with the , please add the following to the code after
$dPosition = rand(0 ,$dLength);    
if (($aStringContent[$dPosition] == $key) || ($aStringContent[$dPosition +1 ] == $key) 
            ||($aStringContent[$dPosition -1] == $key) ){
                    //generate a position again
                    $dPosition = rand(0 ,$dLength);
                }

Comment: It is not worked friend.Anyway thank for your help.
http://demo.webexplorar.com/PHP/keyword-density/2.php

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an array of words from the original string
$words = explode(' ', $string);
// a new array to hold the string we are going to create
$newString = array();
// loop all words of the original string
foreach ($words as $i => $w) {
    // add every word to the new string
    $newString[] = $w;
    // loop all keywords
    foreach ($keywords as $kw => $pos) {
        // if the current index ($i) matches the position
        // add the keywords to the new string aswell
        // note that we add 1 to the index first, 
        // since arrays have zero based indexes
        if ($i+1 == $pos) $newString[] = $kw;
    }
}
// create a string from the array of words we just composed
$filled = implode(' ', $newString);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and appreciate. It is working fine. But it put the keywords in to the string specific position. It is added each keywords 1 time only. That means "Lorem ipsum BAR dolor sit FOOO amet, consecte..." only. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are after, the words in your desired result seem to be placed at random...